# I need help aligning image and links within the same div

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar where the logo and the links are contained within the same div (`.header`). I've got the links to be centered but I can't seem to get the image to be on the same line and centered with the links. I've tried several ways and just can't seem to change anything. Thanks in advance.

```css
.header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4.375rem;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.header img {
  width: 30px;
}
.links {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4.375rem;
}
.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.links li {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="home.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link1.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link3.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link4.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="link5.html">Text</a></li>
      </ul>
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

put the `img` in the `li`? or are you choosing not to do that for other requirement reasons?

```css
.header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4.375rem;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.header img {
  width: 30px;
}
.links {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4.375rem;
}
.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.links li {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="home.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link1.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link3.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link4.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link5.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><img src="logo.png"/></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to utilise either `float: [left/right]` or `display: inline-block`. Currently your navigation bar is taking up full width as it's implicitly set to `display: block`. All the `width: 50%` you've currently set serves to do is limit the contents of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem isn't with the image, it's with the `<ul>`.  Lists are block elements, so following elements will start on the next line by default. The easiest fix is to change the display type of the `<ul>` to `inline-block`.  This keeps the block aspects you need (centered), but also allows the image to go to the same line as the list.

```
.links {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4.375rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```